# How to retrieve stored data from blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, nodejs, ipfs, embark

I built a dapp integrating IPFS and Ethereum, in which the blockchain will store (in transaction) the links of every file uploaded to IPFS. But I want to display the IPFS links of all the files I uploaded to IPFS. Is there a way I could do that rather than setting up a DB for storing the links?

I am using embark framework, which will make adding files to IPFS easy,and I also tried to save the links to a file and display it on the web page using 'fs' module in node, but I cannot create an object of the 'fs' module in the dapp;

Is there a way I could display the links in a web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may store links in Ethereum blockchain using smart contract similar to this one:

```solidity
contract LinkRegistrar {
  address private owner;

  event Link (string link);

  constructor () public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function registerLink (string memory link) public {
    require (msg.sender == owner);
    emit Link (link);
  }
}
```

This will put links into transaction receipts in form of logged events, where links could be easily queried from.  See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/contracts.html#events) for more details about what events are and how to query them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `fs` module in the browser, it is only available on nodejs. You could use a smart contract or the HTML5 localstorage API to store the links.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store all the links, you can achieve this by using IPFS itself just by storing a single link.

1. Store all the links of the files you save to IPFS in a single CSV file and save it to IPFS, get its link and save it into your smart-contract or database.
2. Whenever you add/remove a file, get that CSV file, modify it and save it again to IPFS, then update the CSV reference Link.

Sounds hacky, but this way you will save a lot of storage if you have a large number of files.